# CKEditor insert text get previous range

Tags: html, ckeditor, range

in CKEditor I would like to insert some HTML and then put cursor on some position in that previously inserted HTML.

I can insert it and cursor goes at the end of insertion - new line. But then, If I get range, I don't get inserted text's range, but new line's range.

So my question is: is it possible to get inserted text's range and if yes - how?

Thanks for answers and hints

Answer (score 0):

Nope and yes. CKEditor's API will not give you such information, but of course it is possible to get it. It's non trivial and requires choosing the right solution to the situation. The more general situation, the harder the problem is. You can start from adding markers to the text you  insert but in some cases you may end up implementing your own text insertion mechanism.